# Attaching a function to the window object not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, requirejs, window-object

I have a function defined on the window object somewhat like this

```
window["functionName"] = function(){
    // code here
};
```

Now whenever I need that function I just call

```
window["functionName"]();
```

This works well in all browsers except IE8. IE8 throws an error

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'functionName'
```

I googled for explainations but didnt find any.

**EDIT:** After a long time debugging I got the cause of the error

Actually the above function definition was inside another function.

```
function otherFunction(){
    window["functionName"] = function(){
        // code here
    };
    // code here
}
```

When I moved it outside it looked to work fine.

```
window["functionName"] = function(){
    // code here
};

function otherFunction(){
    // code here        
}
```

But I still cannot understand why this weird behaviour?

Comment: Can you link to a test case?

Comment: well i setup a test case here and surprisingly it is working very well here http://jsfiddle.net/C9g8H/. Is it because my code is modular and distributed accordingly using require js?

Comment: Is it possible that there is a node with the id that you wish to use to hold the function? There are some 'protected'\read only properties that will trigger this type of error in earlier IEs.

Comment: @MasterAM, got the cause of the error. Edited my question

Comment: I do not have any machines with IE8 at the moment, so I cannot test this matter further. Why are you using window's global namespace anyway? Would it not be better to narrow down your use of namespace to a single global name that would hold all other global variables?

Comment: Well, the current code was wired that way and I did not want to change that